# Folder created in Dockerfile not visible after running container

Tags: docker

I am using Docker and have a docker-compose.yml and a Dockerfile. In my Dockerfile, I create a folder. When I build the container, I can see that the folder is created, but when I run the container, I can see all the files, but the folder that I created during the container build is not visible.

Both of these files are in the same location.
Here is docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: tail -f /dev/null        #command to leave the container on
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mkdir "test"
RUN ls
```

To build the container I use the command: `docker-compose build --progress=plain --no-cache`. Command `RUN ls` from Dockerfile prints me that there are 3 files: Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and created in Dockerfile test directory.

When my container is running and i'm entering the docker to check which files are there i haven't directory 'test'.

I probably have 'volumes' mounted incorrectly. When I delete them, after entering the container, I see the 'test' folder. Unfortunately,

**I want my files in the container and on the host to be sync**.

This is a simple example. I have the same thing creating dependencies in nodejs. I think that the question written in this way will be more helpful to others.

Comment: The volume "overrides" the content already present in folder `/app` within the container (it basically hides whatever was present in `/app` before the volume got mounted). Keep in mind that volumes are only present at container runtime, not image buildtime.

Answer (score 2):

When you mount the same volume in docker-compose it will mount that folder to the running image, and `test` folder will be overwritten by mounted folder.

This may work for you (to create folder from docker-compose file), but im not really sure in your use case:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: mkdir /app/test && tail -f /dev/null
```

Based on your comment, below is an example on how i would use Dockerfile to build node packages and save node_modules back to host:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

COPY . /app

RUN npm install
```

Sh

```
#!/bin/bash

docker build -t my-image .

container_id=$(docker run -d my-image)

docker cp $container_id:/app/node_modules .

docker stop $container_id
docker rm $container_id
```

Or more simple way, on how I use to do it, is just to run the docker image and ssh into it:
`docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/home/app node:14.19-alpine`
ssh into running container, perform npm commands then exit;

Comment: Thanks for your replying. Directory 'test' is only example. I want my docker to create these files and make them visible both in the running container and in the host files. In my case i install node_modules in dockerfile but it isn't visible in host. I want link files in container and host but this doesn't work.

Comment: In short. I want my docker to download files from the project (COPY command). But I also want the things I do with those files in the container to change the files in the host as well.

Comment: A Docker container is generally prohibited from editing files on the host.  What behavior do you expect to happen if the container starts, and the host directory and image are already different?  Docker's behavior here is self-consistent and works the same way as other Unix mounts.

Comment: this needs to happen during run-time. docker containers are generally "static" should do no  any purpose other than installing necessary packages and applications.

Comment: I expect dockerfile to install dependencies for me using nodejs and pass the node_modules directory to the host. I don't want to copy other files to the host. I did the above example to make it easier to explain what I want. I wanted to hardcode a 'test' folder in Dockerfike and pass it to the host. I want npm install to work similarly on a container. It created node_modules and passed them to the host to be in these two places. That's why I create a 'test' folder in the Dockerfile, because if I can pass it to the host, node_modules will too.

Comment: in that case i would not use docker-compose, but you can run series of commands to perform this task, i will put example in my answer.